# ObjectDisposedException when getting foreign key field

Tags: entity-framework

I created my model using Db Context Generator, using EF 4.
My model is like this:

Program Table:
ID
Name

Group Table:
ID
Name
ProgramID (Associated to Program.ID)

I want to display these columns in my grid:

Program.Name - Group.Name

But grdGroups.DataSource = db.Groups.ToList()

doesn't return Program.Name

When I try to this I get ObjectDisposedException.

```
Partial Public Class Group 
    Public ReadOnly Property ProgramName() As String 
        Get 
            Return Program.Name 
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

What's the best way to return the Program.Name to include it in the grid datasource?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I try to this I get
>   ObjectDisposedException

The problem is lazy loading - EF did not materialize the related `Program` entity, hence when you try to access `Program.Name` it will try and re-query the DB, but the context has been disposed at this point, so you get an exception.

You can use an `Include()` query when you retrieve your `Group` entity, to specify that you also want to load the related `Program` entity, i.e. :

```
var groups = context.Groups.Include(x => x.Program);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!
grdGroups.DataSource = db.Groups.Include("Program").ToList()
worked for me!

Comment: @BrokenGlass When I tried `Include(x => x.Program)` I got an error that it can't convert a lambda to a string. I had to use `Include("Program")` instead. Do you know why this is the case?